# Outputting HTML in twig file using Bolt CMS

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I have a problem outputting html in my twig. I am using Bolt CMS 3.2

```
{% for item in menu %}
    <li class="list-inline {{ item.path == '/#' ? 'dropdown' }}">
        <a href="{{ item.path }}" >
            {% autoescape %}
                {% set caret = '<span class="caret"></span>' %}
                {{ (item.path == '/#') ? caret|raw : item.label }}
            {% endautoescape %}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it keeps outputting the html as a string. I used the autoescape value but it does nothing here. did i use it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
{% autoescape false %}
   {% set caret = '<span class="caret"></span>' %}
   {{ (item.path == '/#') ? caret|raw : item.label }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Source : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html